# Extjs 6.2. GridPanel with colSpan in renderer

Tags: extjs, html-table, renderer, gridpanel

I'm using Extjs Widgets in workflow based application to create a WebApplication.

Now I'm trying to get a Grid with x rows, and underneath each row there could be several rows which should have colSpan.

Because of using these widget I'm not able to change config on the grid itself. So I tried to use the renderer.

Has someone an idea, how to make this possible?

[Here is my fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2flu)

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want to achieve ?

Comment: No easy way, no. You might want to look into this: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/examples/kitchensink/?classic#row-expander-grid

Comment: Let's say that this is a really really complicated issue, since ExtJS grids are not intended for use with colspan or rowspan. You may try to start here: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?296583